# How Do I Save a Multiple Select Field in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

Here is my current code to save the multiple select field values. It is only saving one (1) value, not each value that I select.

```
    public function booked_save_calendars_custom_fields( $term_id ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
            $t_id = ($term_id);
            $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
            $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
            foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
                if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
                    $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
                }
            }
            update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
        }
    }
```

This is saving a custom meta field for a taxonomy in WordPress.

Comment: why aren't you looping over the $term_meta keys but the input?

Answer (score 0):

With your limited information from which I have understood I could only able to answer this much. If it is upto your need then approach it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="fruits[]" multiple>
         <option value='apple'>Apple</option>
         <option value='orange'>Orange</option>
         <option value='mango'>Mango</option>
         <option value='grapes'>Grapes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>   
 </form>

// The name attribute for multi select field should be of array type

<?php
if(isset($_POST['fruits']))
{
    foreach($_POST['fruits'] as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $value."<br>";
        // do something required
    }
    // or if you want to insert it in db just convert it into JSON data
    json_encode($_POST['fruits']);
    // proceed the insertion query
    // Note The db field for the json data should have text data type
}
?>
```